# Is there a way to control master volume in vse?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I know that you can change the volume of selected sound track but its annoying if you have many of those.Is there a way to change master volume or are there any sound mixer options available?All answers are welcomed :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a setting under scene data properties, here:

[image]

In v3.6.0:

[image]

If affects the current scene. So if you use multiple scenes to render things and a different scene to do the video editing, change the value in that video editing scene.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! God bless you, you just saved me adjusting the volume of a ton of audio strips 