# what tools can be used to manage/balance audio volume in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I was recently using the VSE to put together video to match a narration.  The quality of the audio recording was pretty weak (did it with my laptop and a headset in several different places over a couple of days).  One thing I noticed was that the volume could vary pretty drastically.  I think I was using a volume factor of 4 on a couple of the strips.

Does blender have any ability to graph or otherwise measure the volume to help you balance things out between different audio strips?

Comment: see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/sound.html and related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62847/is-there-a-way-to-control-master-volume-in-vse/62852#62852

Comment: The first link has absolutely no mention of tools that would help you balance things out between different audio strips.  The second link references what looks like a master volume that would affect all strips, not help you balance the levels between two different strips.

Comment: from the manual "Animating Audio Track Properties

To animate sound strips simply hit I over any of its values. Examples of animating an audio strip are to fade in/out background music or to adjust volume levels. Layered/crossed sound strips are added together; the lower channel does not override and cut out higher channels (unlike image and video strips). This makes Blender an audio mixer. By adding audio tracks and using the curves to adjust each tracks’ sound level, you have an automated dynamic multi-track audio mixer!" so, then you can simply use usual f-curves...

Comment: or maybe I didn't get what you need...

Comment: I already know how to set the volume and I know how to animate properties. What is currently missing is measurements to help me figure out how loud each strip is so I can adjust them to have similar volumes, especially since I have around 20 different audio strips spread out across 3 minutes.  I'd like to be reasonably confident that my last narration track is about the same volume as my first.